# Icons utility list not fully showing

Tags: icon

I've got some issues regarding the list of icons utility. Indeed, the list is only showing icons names from "A" to "N" but I can't have the rest from "O" to "Z". Then it only said "No matches found". Even if I try to write it manually (like utility:setup_assistant_guide for example), it doesn't work. Any idea to show them all?
[image]

Comment: Hi. Where are you looking at the list? Do you mean in the [catalog](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility) (which for me is fully populated)?

Comment: No sorry, I mean when I try to show them on my appexchange components.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more detail as to exactly where you are not seeing the names. A screenshot may also help provide context if this isn't in code or your IDE.

Comment: Ok it's done, I've had a screenshot of the item where the issue is.

Comment: Nice to have this partial screenshot. The problem is, I have no idea what the context is for this screenshot. You said it's something to do with an AppExchange component...? Which component? Your own or some AppExchange listed component? If the former, can you provide a code snippet showing how the component builds the list? If the latter, should you not contact the AppExchange listing's developer about this?